# Is the viewer in examples a variant of the carousel on the search demo?

Tags: amp-html

Is this something we could use to display AMP documents in our sites? It's not clear from code how to use it.

Comment: Well you **can** just load them normally, they are standard and complete html pages - the browser renders them. Or can load them in an (even full-screen) iframe. The search demo does use a more advanced loader (via Googles CDN), but its not needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is a variant of the code running in Search using the same interface. This isn't meant as production code, but really only to test AMP file / viewer interaction with a super simple viewer.

Our longer term plan is to provide SDKs for web and webview wrappers for native apps to make it super easy to integrate AMPs into existing apps. E.g. we'd love to have an `<amp-view src="…">` web component for integration into web apps.